# Cordova build failed and unable to find valid certification path

Tags: java, cordova, security

I installed Apache Cordoba and run:

```
cordova build android --debug --stacktrace
```

To this I get an error:

```
Caused by: org.gradle.internal.resource.transport.http.HttpRequestException: Could not GET 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/github/dcendents/android-maven-gradle-plugin/2.1/android-maven-gradle-plugin-2.1.pom'.      
Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
```

In android studio the same:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZRbbN.jpg)

I import from serticate `jcenter.bintray.com` via java tools
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uvx6m.jpg)

And run command:

```
java SSLPoke jcenter.bintray.com 443
```

I got an answer: SUCCESS

My java:

```
D:\dev>java -version
Picked up _JAVA_OPTIONS: -Xmx512M
java version "1.8.0_161"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_161-b12)
Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (build 25.161-b12, mixed mode)
```

What else do i need with these certificates?

Comment: It seems the issue is specific to your environment, maybe a firewall is blocking access.

Comment: `wget` downloads the file to the address that is in error

Answer (score 2):

Add both http and https proxy like following

```
gradlew -Dhttp.proxyHost=127.0.0.1 -Dhttp.proxyPort=8080 -Dhttps.proxyHost=127.0.0.1 -Dhttps.proxyPort=8144
```

Comment: did you mean what to do `gradle -Dhttp.proxyHost=127.0.0.1 ...` ?

Comment: 'gradlew' is not recognized as an internal or external command but simple `gradle` is called

Comment: Ok you can try with gradle or you can try ./gradlew

Comment: I try `gradle -Dhttp.proxyHost=127.0.0.1 -Dhttp.proxyPort=8080
gradle -Dhttps.proxyHost=127.0.0.1 -Dhttps.proxyPort=8144` but don`t help

Comment: Check this SO post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39323145/jcenter-bintray-com443-failed-to-respond-error-in-android-studio

Comment: I again added certificate but not result